# ASP.NET Core DB-first Entity Framework Core can not auto increment primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project. I am using the database first approach with SQL Server and generated my models using EF Core.

I want the primary key to be auto incremented. Everything seems to work fine on the first entry in which it defaults my primary key (`PimId`) to 0. However, on the second insertion, the primary key remains 0.

My onModelCreate function

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ImportPim>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PimId);
            entity.ToTable("Import_PIM");

            entity.Property(e => e.PimId)
                .HasColumnName("PIM_Id")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.CliId).HasColumnName("CLI_Id");

            entity.Property(e => e.PimAccountNumber)
                .HasColumnName("PIM_AccountNumber")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
```

This was generated by EF Core, I have tried changing `ValueGeneratedNever()` to `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` but I get a saving error in SQL Server.

Any suggestions on how to do?

Comment: don't you need to add ValueGenerationOnAdd instead of ValueGeneratedNever

Comment: Does your table column have IDENTITY(1,1)? I generate models from databases, and usually the identity key property doesn't need to be specified in `OnModelCreating`

Comment: It is useless change it in `OnModelCreating` since you are using DB first. You need to set the primary key AUTO_INCREMENT in sql server, then re-generate the models.

Comment: @mj1313 an insane Thanks. It seems like the onModelCreating does not have any effect if you're using the DB first approach.

Answer (score 1):

ValueGeneratedOnAdd() should works. If not, make sure that you set Identity for PimId in your table in SQL Server.

```
    entity.Property(e => e.PimId)
        .HasColumnName("PIM_Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as identity (Auto increment) like this:

```js
modelBuilder.Entity<ImportPim>().Property(entity => entity.PimId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```